# Is it possible to have the updated CSS in WKWebview?

Tags: css, swift, wkwebview

in my app I am using WKwebView, which gets its style from a CSS file on backend.
When I change the CSS on server, I am not able to see the changes. The only way to see the changes is to unistall and reinstall the app.
I tried the following method from  WKNavigationdelegate. It did work for some times but not all the times.

```
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.reloadFromOrigin()
    }
```

How is it possible to set the WKWebview to reload the updated css file?

Thanks very much.

Comment: you could do something on your backend <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />

Comment: By adding a timestamp to your js and css you can easily avoid caching